# How to exclude a directory or partition on pmlogger scan?

Tags: fedora, find, disk, io, selinux

As on the details below it look like that the cause of the problem is the `pmlogger` is spawning the find command. And its takes a long time for the `find` to scan all the files in one of my partition. And it happens that it is my backup partition, so it is expected there are so many files there.

Honestly this was not happening before, I am just getting a burst read io for a few minutes and will stop, but now it takes hours.

As requested I will change my question.

How should I exclude a directory or partition to pmlogger? Cause I don't know if it's good idea to disable the whole `pmlogger` and also I don't know why `pmlogger` doing this. So if I can  make to exclude my backup directory to `pmlogger` maybe I can narrow more the problem.

Thanks

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I forgot when exactly it started, If I am correct that was when I update all packages last week.
On iotop the command is `find . -daystart -name NoSuchFile`, I dont know what it does to the files it reading, when I tried to use `fatrace` it open a lot of files per second.

Also SELinux keeps telling about this `SELinux is preventing find from open access on the directory /sys/kernel/config.` and some read access on **irq, dev, usermodehelper, net, rpc, and pcp.WXW8e2p7o**.

Anyone can give me some light on this and how should I deal it?

Thanks

**Edit**

This will just happen after boot up, then will last an hour or so.

Then when I execute `sudo fatrace | grep '(7290)'` *7290 is the find pid. it will log this

```
find(7290): RC /mnt/Time Machine/...
find(7290): O /mnt/Time Machine/...
find(7290): R /mnt/Time Machine/...
and so on...
```

BTW when I execute that, at that time it accessing my laptop second  hard drive(Ext4). this hard drive I think it quite old around 2 and half years, But I checked the Overall assessment on SMART Data & Self-Test is still OK.

Here is the screenshot of the iotop.
[image]

Here is the output of free

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       12140160     1820112     3253992      266344     7066056     9736188
Swap:       6143996           0     6143996
```

And here is the output of vmstat

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  1      0 3256144 4322284 2770984    0    0   893    28  761 1914  8  4 70 18  0
```

**More Edit**

I found pstree command, and found this

```
systemd───pmlogger───pmlogger_check───pmlogger_daily───find
```

And I check the pmlogger on systmectl

```
● pmlogger.service - Performance Metrics Archive Logger
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/pmlogger.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-12-27 11:37:16 PST; 38min ago
     Docs: man:pmlogger(1)
  Process: 1935 ExecStart=/usr/share/pcp/lib/pmlogger start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7150 (pmlogger)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 6.6G
   CGroup: /system.slice/pmlogger.service
           ├─2043 /usr/bin/sh /usr/share/pcp/lib/pmlogger start
           ├─2047 /usr/bin/sh /usr/libexec/pcp/bin/pmlogger_check -V
           ├─7150 /usr/libexec/pcp/bin/pmlogger -P -r -T24h10m -c config.default -v 100mb -m pmlogger_check 20181227.11.37
           ├─7264 /usr/bin/sh /usr/libexec/pcp/bin/pmlogger_daily -K -V
           └─7290 find . -daystart -name NoSuchFile

Dec 27 11:37:05 fedora-acer systemd[1]: Starting Performance Metrics Archive Logger...
Dec 27 11:37:05 fedora-acer pmlogger[1935]: Starting pmlogger ...
Dec 27 11:37:05 fedora-acer systemd[1]: pmlogger.service: Can't open PID file /run/pcp/pmlogger.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Dec 27 11:37:16 fedora-acer systemd[1]: pmlogger.service: Supervising process 7150 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
Dec 27 11:37:16 fedora-acer systemd[1]: Started Performance Metrics Archive Logger.
```

Comment: This looks like a prank.  Have you tried killing the process?

Comment: @Fabby I would normal behaviour is being described.

Comment: There are too many variables you are not telling us about to give a meaningful answer. Age of equipment, model, technology or hard disk / storage, what does the VM does, hypervisor, logs, load of vm, and even then, the question might still be vague. I advise investing more time on questions

Comment: Please add output of free to the question and vmstat. If talking about iotop, outputs of iotop and other tools being talked about

Comment: @Fabby I didn't, because I thought I could broke something and make it worst.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro and Fabby I add more details, I hope I fill some missing details.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I just edited the question, I hope I deliver it right.